# Getx using obx for RxList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

so i have a list in Getx controller then i have a multiple component in a listview and i put every component with different list and i wrap the listview parent with obx but it give me this warning and not updating the state without the list added with .refresh()

i just want to wrap the widget with obx then update but it throws error

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes that if you are still learning flutter that you will miss the basic of flutter but im using it for work for easier and faster working project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, for RxList we just need to add  .toList() after the list name list.toList() different with other value using  .value